# How do we alter VirtoCommerce 2 configuration or software to combine order create, invoice and order paid emails into a single email

Tags: virtocommerce

In VirtoCommerce 2 we would like to send a single email with the order contents and payment information in clear text (not PDF).  Where do we configure this, or alter software to achieve this result?

Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Turn off default notifications in settings (Order.SendOrderNotifications)
2. Create a custom module using VS Template and implement custom IEventHandler.

These can be a good example of how to implement Order Changed Event Handler.

https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-module-order/blob/master/VirtoCommerce.OrderModule.Data/Handlers/SendNotificationsOrderChangedEventHandler.cs#L20

https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-samples/tree/master/WhatsAppNotification